# Inserting a variable array of data into a PostgreSQL column

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

Got a shortcoming of brain.exe for some reason currently.

I am using Node.js and node-postgres to query my DB.

I am trying to insert an array of text, basically, into a PostgreSQL column.

logging the array with JSON.stringify() looks like this:

```
["id1","id2","id3"]
```

Will I just be able to

```
'INSERT INTO table (array) VALUES ($1)' [data]'
```

?

(extremely simplified - The data array is variable in length)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```js
import { pgclient } from '../../db';

(async function test() {
  try {
    await pgclient.connect();
    // create table
    await pgclient.query(`
      CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS my_table (
        id serial PRIMARY KEY,
        arr varchar[]
      )
    `);
    // test
    const array = ['id1', 'id2', 'id3'];
    await pgclient.query(`INSERT INTO my_table (arr) VALUES ($1)`, [array]);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } finally {
    pgclient.end();
  }
})();
```

After executed above code, check the database:

```sh
node-sequelize-examples=# select * from "my_table";
 id |      arr
----+---------------
  1 | {id1,id2,id3}
(1 row)
```